# Vuex state getter not working inside the vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vue-composition-api, vuex4

Trying to implement the new Vue composition API I ran into an issue, my vuex state values are not working and it will return an $store undefined error. When I check if my language state is set it is set so theres data present. I could not find any good information about this but I did find some helper plugin but I dont want to use plugins for every issue so is there a way to do this?

I am using vue 3 with vuex 4

```
export default {
    setup (props, context) {
        console.log(context.root.$store.getters['i18n/language'])//not working
        // more logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the composable function called `useStore` to get the store instance :

```
import {useStore} from 'vuex'
export default {
    setup (props, context) {
        const store=useStore()
        console.log(store.getters['i18n/language'])
    }
}
```